# Language switching fails for multilingual drupal site

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to build a multilingual web-site with Drupal 6 and currently I ran into a problem switching UI language. Switching language from the default one using language switcher block doesn't work and displays error message:

*The selected file could not be copied, because no file by that name exists. Please check that you supplied the correct filename.*

The following message gets written to a log:

*An error occurred during creation of the JavaScript translation file for the language `[language_name]`.*

Drupal 6 on Windows and IIS 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a permissions issue. Is your files directory writable? Check the status page (Admin > Reports > Status report). You might also want to check out these similar issues from other Drupal users running on IIS:

- http://drupal.org/node/522066#comment-1822892
- http://drupal.org/node/776392#comment-2867646

Comment: I suspected this had to be a permissions issue - giving write access on "c:\windows\temp" for IUSR fixed the problem (as suggested in the first link). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have a directory called "languages" inside "sites/default/files" and make sure that this directory is writable.

If this doesn't solve the problem, check if there's a Drupal variable called "`locale_js_directory`" (in the "`variable`" table in MySQL) and check its value. If this exists, its the name of the directory  in which the JS file will be created (instead of in the "languages", which is the default). Check if this directory exists and is writable as well.

Comment: Thanks, but folder "languages" is there and is writable for everyone (and still empty).

Comment: I edited the answer. If that doesn't help, I'm out of ideas, but you can try debugging Drupal to see where it's failing. In particular, the 2nd error message you posted is in the locale.inc core Drupal file.

Comment: Ok, so the problem was due to a permission, but for "c:\windows\temp" folder. After giving write access on "c:\windows\temp" to IUSR a new js file has been created in "languages".